# Packer amazon-chroot builder Error creating root volume: InvalidSnapshot.NotFound: Snapshot does not exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, packer

I have an interesting requirement of running a Packer amazon-chroot build off a temporary running Packer amazon-ebs instance due to some custom root block device disk partitioning scheme for the resulting AMI. My amazon-ebs instance is utilizing two launch block device mappings, a root disk for the parent RHEL8 OS, and a secondary empty device where I want to use the amazon-chroot builder to load RHEL8 OS with custom partitioning.

Running the first parent Packer amazon-ebs build in debug mode, I can verify the disks are present on the EC2 instance as expected. When I fire off the Packer amazon-chroot build on the parent EC2 server, I'm getting the following error message:

```bash
...
==> amibuild.amazon-chroot.source-ami: Pausing after run of step 'StepInstanceInfo'. Press enter to continue.
    amibuild.amazon-chroot.source-ami: Found Image ID: ami-0238411fb452f8275
==> amibuild.amazon-chroot.source-ami: Pausing after run of step 'StepSourceAMIInfo'. Press enter to continue.
==> amibuild.amazon-chroot.source-ami: Checking the root device on source AMI...
==> amibuild.amazon-chroot.source-ami: Pausing after run of step 'StepCheckRootDevice'. Press enter to continue.
==> amibuild.amazon-chroot.source-ami: Pausing after run of step 'StepFlock'. Press enter to continue.
==> amibuild.amazon-chroot.source-ami: Pausing after run of step 'StepPrepareDevice'. Press enter to continue.
==> amibuild.amazon-chroot.source-ami: Creating the root volume...
==> amibuild.amazon-chroot.source-ami: Error creating root volume: InvalidSnapshot.NotFound: Snapshot does not exist
==> amibuild.amazon-chroot.source-ami:  status code: 400, request id: f44d58c0-2b7f-4799-94da-371bf2b49651
...
```

Searching on the error message isn't providing much in terms of actionable changes for me to test on the amazon-chroot builder. I'm looking for some guidance on expectation of the amazon-chroot builder settings to get the initial RHEL8 OS loaded on the secondary empty disk of the EC2 instance.

The following are the pertinent settings of my amazon-ebs and amazon-chroot build properties.

**amazon-ebs**

```
source "amazon-ebs" "parent" {
    skip_create_ami = true
    region = var.aws_region
    source_ami = var.source_ami_id
    ami_users = var.ami_users
    snapshot_users = var.ami_users
    source_ami_filter {
        filters = {
            name = var.source_ami_filter_name
            architecture = "arm64"
            root-device-type = "ebs"
            state = "available"
            virtualization-type = "hvm"
        }
        owners = [ var.source_ami_owners ]
        most_recent = true
    }
    instance_type = "m7g.medium"
    launch_block_device_mappings {
        device_name = "/dev/sda1"
        volume_type = var.volume_type
        volume_size = var.launch_block_device_mappings_volume_size
        delete_on_termination = true
    }
    launch_block_device_mappings {
        device_name = "/dev/sdf"
        volume_type = var.volume_type
        volume_size = var.launch_block_device_mappings_volume_size
        delete_on_termination = true
    }
...
```

**amazon-chroot**

```
source "amazon-chroot" "source-ami" {
    region = var.aws_region
    source_ami = var.source_ami_id
    ami_users = var.ami_users
    snapshot_users = var.ami_users
    source_ami_filter {
        filters = {
            name = var.source_ami_filter_name
            architecture = "arm64"
            root-device-type = "ebs"
            state = "available"
            virtualization-type = "hvm"
        }
        owners = [ var.source_ami_owners ]
        most_recent = true
    }
    nvme_device_path = "/dev/nvme1n1p"
    device_path = "/dev/sdf"
    root_device_name = "/dev/sda1"
    root_volume_size = var.launch_block_device_mappings_volume_size
    ami_block_device_mappings {
        device_name = "/dev/sdf"
        volume_type = var.volume_type
        volume_size = var.launch_block_device_mappings_volume_size
        delete_on_termination = true
    }
...
```

Note, I'm using a `m7g.medium` instance type for the parent EC2 instance, which exposes NVMe drives. I can verify the drives look like I am expecting on the parent EC2 instance with the following:

```bash
[root@ip-172-31-77-18 packer]# lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
nvme0n1     259:0    0   10G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0  200M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0  512M  0 part /boot
└─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0  9.3G  0 part /
nvme1n1     259:4    0   10G  0 disk
```

According to [Packer docs](https://developer.hashicorp.com/packer/plugins/builders/amazon/chroot#using-instances-with-nvme-block-devices), I need to set the `nvme_device_path` property defined, but I'm just not clear on the other settings.

I can also verify both the amazon-ebs and amazon-chroot builds are using the same source AMI in the logs:

```bash
==> amibuild.amazon-chroot.source-ami: Gathering information about this EC2 instance...
==> amibuild.amazon-chroot.source-ami: Pausing after run of step 'StepInstanceInfo'. Press enter to continue.
    amibuild.amazon-chroot.source-ami: Found Image ID: ami-0238411fb452f8275
```

and

```bash
==> amibuild.amazon-ebs.source-ami: Pausing after run of step 'StepPreValidate'. Press enter to continue.
    amibuild.amazon-ebs.source-ami: Found Image ID: ami-0238411fb452f8275
```

Just not sure where the `Error creating root volume: InvalidSnapshot.NotFound: Snapshot does not exist` error message is originating or what it refers to.

**EDIT**
Including Packer Log output of error:

```bash
...
==> amibuild.amazon-chroot.source-ami: Gathering information about this EC2 instance...
2023/04/05 18:13:54 packer-builder-amazon-chroot plugin: Instance ID: i-0d352db9ab0878fa2
2023/04/05 18:13:54 packer-builder-amazon-chroot plugin: Using AMI Filters {
2023/04/05 18:13:54 packer-builder-amazon-chroot plugin:   Filters: [
2023/04/05 18:13:54 packer-builder-amazon-chroot plugin:     {
2023/04/05 18:13:54 packer-builder-amazon-chroot plugin:       Name: "name",
2023/04/05 18:13:54 packer-builder-amazon-chroot plugin:       Values: ["RHEL-8.6.0_HVM-*-arm64-2-Hourly2-GP2"]
2023/04/05 18:13:54 packer-builder-amazon-chroot plugin:     },
2023/04/05 18:13:54 packer-builder-amazon-chroot plugin:     {
2023/04/05 18:13:54 packer-builder-amazon-chroot plugin:       Name: "root-device-type",
2023/04/05 18:13:54 packer-builder-amazon-chroot plugin:       Values: ["ebs"]
2023/04/05 18:13:54 packer-builder-amazon-chroot plugin:     },
2023/04/05 18:13:54 packer-builder-amazon-chroot plugin:     {
2023/04/05 18:13:54 packer-builder-amazon-chroot plugin:       Name: "state",
2023/04/05 18:13:54 packer-builder-amazon-chroot plugin:       Values: ["available"]
2023/04/05 18:13:54 packer-builder-amazon-chroot plugin:     },
2023/04/05 18:13:54 packer-builder-amazon-chroot plugin:     {
2023/04/05 18:13:54 packer-builder-amazon-chroot plugin:       Name: "virtualization-type",
2023/04/05 18:13:54 packer-builder-amazon-chroot plugin:       Values: ["hvm"]
2023/04/05 18:13:54 packer-builder-amazon-chroot plugin:     },
2023/04/05 18:13:54 packer-builder-amazon-chroot plugin:     {
2023/04/05 18:13:54 packer-builder-amazon-chroot plugin:       Name: "architecture",
2023/04/05 18:13:54 packer-builder-amazon-chroot plugin:       Values: ["arm64"]
2023/04/05 18:13:54 packer-builder-amazon-chroot plugin:     }
2023/04/05 18:13:54 packer-builder-amazon-chroot plugin:   ],
2023/04/05 18:13:54 packer-builder-amazon-chroot plugin:   Owners: ["309956199498"]
2023/04/05 18:13:54 packer-builder-amazon-chroot plugin: }
    amibuild.amazon-chroot.source-ami: Found Image ID: ami-0238411fb452f8275
==> amibuild.amazon-chroot.source-ami: Checking the root device on source AMI...
==> amibuild.amazon-chroot.source-ami: Creating the root volume...
2023/04/05 18:13:55 packer-builder-amazon-chroot plugin: Obtaining lock: /var/lock/packer-chroot/lock
2023/04/05 18:13:55 packer-builder-amazon-chroot plugin: Device: /dev/sdh
2023/04/05 18:13:55 packer-builder-amazon-chroot plugin: Searching for root device of the image (/dev/sda1)
2023/04/05 18:13:55 packer-builder-amazon-chroot plugin: Create args: {
2023/04/05 18:13:55 packer-builder-amazon-chroot plugin:   AvailabilityZone: "us-east-1f",
2023/04/05 18:13:55 packer-builder-amazon-chroot plugin:   Encrypted: false,
2023/04/05 18:13:55 packer-builder-amazon-chroot plugin:   Size: 10,
2023/04/05 18:13:55 packer-builder-amazon-chroot plugin:   SnapshotId: "snap-0221afb3433c26165",
2023/04/05 18:13:55 packer-builder-amazon-chroot plugin:   VolumeType: "gp2"
2023/04/05 18:13:55 packer-builder-amazon-chroot plugin: }
==> amibuild.amazon-chroot.source-ami: Error creating root volume: InvalidSnapshot.NotFound: Snapshot does not exist
==> amibuild.amazon-chroot.source-ami:  status code: 400, request id: d54088bb-481c-4e46-8bc4-022c365d56ef
...
```

Packer version 1.8.6

And the source AMI image details:

```json
{
    "Images": [
        {
            "Architecture": "arm64",
            "CreationDate": "2022-05-05T11:09:04.000Z",
            "ImageId": "ami-0238411fb452f8275",
            "ImageLocation": "amazon/RHEL-8.6.0_HVM-20220503-arm64-2-Hourly2-GP2",
            "ImageType": "machine",
            "Public": true,
            "OwnerId": "309956199498",
            "PlatformDetails": "Red Hat Enterprise Linux",
            "UsageOperation": "RunInstances:0010",
            "State": "available",
            "BlockDeviceMappings": [
                {
                    "DeviceName": "/dev/sda1",
                    "Ebs": {
                        "DeleteOnTermination": true,
                        "SnapshotId": "snap-0221afb3433c26165",
                        "VolumeSize": 10,
                        "VolumeType": "gp2",
                        "Encrypted": false
                    }
                }
            ],
            "Description": "Provided by Red Hat, Inc.",
            "EnaSupport": true,
            "Hypervisor": "xen",
            "ImageOwnerAlias": "amazon",
            "Name": "RHEL-8.6.0_HVM-20220503-arm64-2-Hourly2-GP2",
            "RootDeviceName": "/dev/sda1",
            "RootDeviceType": "ebs",
            "SriovNetSupport": "simple",
            "VirtualizationType": "hvm",
            "DeprecationTime": "2024-05-05T11:09:04.000Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This does seem odd. Instead of using debug mode, it would probably be more helpful to instead enable full logging with `PACKER_LOG=1`. Check what extra helpful information is evinced from that.

Comment: So it does appear that the verbose logging shows the issue here: the AMI is missing the associated backing snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

I have a discussion topic posted on [Hashicorp's](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/does-amazon-chroot-builder-require-the-source-amis-ebs-snapshot-to-exist-in-my-account/52377) forum looking for an official answer, but I believe I can confirm that the AMI's root block device snapshot has to be present and accessible from the running credentialed entity.

I was able to get around the InvalidSnapshot NotFound error message by creating a baseline AMI in my account sourced from Red Hat's RHEL 8 AMI, then pointing my surrogate parent build to my AMI before invoking my amazon-chroot builder.